# How to show comment at top level, without using a popup?

Tags: usability, layout, comments, interface

If user clicks on add comment, what are other options to show 'comment area' (no popup).

[image]

Comment: In this image i have shown a rollover box, which is not a good idea :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what information you would like to capture and how fast you want the user to leave the comment.

1. Most blogs have 3 input fields. Name, Website, Comment and of course a button Add Comment.
2. If the user is logged in, just a comment field

Comment: In my case, when user fails/pass/block/na a test case, He wants to enter some comment depending on the situation. It will be plain text.

Comment: then just a filed where the user could leave a comment

Comment: I was confused in terms of layout, where it should it come.
Do you think under the title- 130: Restrict..., is a good idea?

Comment: Depends what you want users to comment on, the whole bug or individual steps. But usually the comments are at the bottom of the screen. I wouldn't suggest restricting the comments to 130 letters, the user might not be able to describe the bug in detail if you will.

Comment: That is right approach to follow, comments are at the Bug level, for steps the comments comes under each step. Yes, i should not limit characters. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply make space inside your layout for the comment. Just like what happens on this site if you comment on a question or answer.

Comment: on this site you have to be logged in to leave the comment...

Comment: Oh yeas, i really i liked this. 
Responsive and fluid.

Comment: @nitish what do you mean responsive and fluid?

Comment: I was confused in terms of layout, where it should it come.
Do you think under the title- 130: Restrict..., is a good idea?

Comment: Responsive and fluid: I mean that, it comes with a very subtle animation and when needed (evoked). Does not hinder main task.